# Как исправить метод дизеринга для построения градиента?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, изображения, графика

Есть программа, которая строит матрицу для градиента с помощью дизеринга. В ней реализованы 4 способа: Ordered, Random, Floyd-Steinberg, Jarvis-Judice-Ninke. Я создаю матрицу определенного размера и с помощью одного из методов преобразую её в градиент от белого цвета до чёрного и вывожу результат в файл формата .pgm, тип P5. Если перевести файл в .png, получаю такое изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, при увеличении картинки можно увидеть полосы (если хорошо присмотреться):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это говорит о том, что дизеринг работает не совсем корректно. Для всех методов результат одинаковый. Как исправить эту проблему?

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> make_gradient(int height, int width)
{
    assert(height > 0 && width > 0);

    int cf = height / 255;
    int color = 0;
    vector<vector<int>> result(height, vector<int>(width));
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i += cf)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cf; ++j)
        {
            fill(result[i + j].begin(), result[i + j].end(), color % 255);
        }
        color++;
    }
    stable_sort(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> ordered_dither(int height, int width, vector<vector<int>> result)
{
    int ditherSize = 4;
    int diterLookup[] = { 0, 8, 2, 10, 12, 4, 14, 6, 3, 11, 1, 9, 15, 7, 13, 5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int xlocal = i%ditherSize;
            int ylocal = j%ditherSize;
            int requiredShade = diterLookup[xlocal + ylocal * 4] * 255 / 16;
            if ((requiredShade > 0) && (requiredShade < 1))
            {
                if (requiredShade >= (result[i][j] % 1)) {
                    result[i][j] = floor(result[i][j]);
                }
                else {
                    result[i][j] = ceil(result[i][j]);
                }
            }
            else requiredShade = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> random_dither(int height, int width, vector<vector<int>> result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int requiredShade = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            if ((requiredShade > 0) && (requiredShade < 1))
            {
                if (requiredShade >= (result[i][j] % 1)) {
                    result[i][j] = floor(result[i][j]);
                }
                else {
                    result[i][j] = ceil(result[i][j]);
                }
            }
            else requiredShade = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> fs_dither(int height, int width, vector<vector<int>> result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int oldpixel = result[i][j];
            int newpixel = round(result[i][j]);;
            result[i][j] = newpixel;
            int quanterror = oldpixel - newpixel;
            if (j < width - 1) {
                result[i][j + 1] += quanterror * 7 / 16;
            }
            if (i < height - 1) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    result[i + 1][j - 1] += quanterror * 3 / 16;
                }
                result[i + 1][j] += quanterror * 5 / 16;
                if (j < width - 1) {
                    result[i + 1][j + 1] += quanterror * 1 / 16;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> jjn_dither(int height, int width, vector<vector<int>> result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int oldpixel = result[i][j];
            int newpixel = round(result[i][j]);;
            result[i][j] = newpixel;
            int quanterror = oldpixel - newpixel;
            if (j < width - 1) {
                result[i][j + 1] += quanterror * 7 / 48;
                if (j<width - 2)
                    result[i][j + 2] += quanterror * 5 / 48;
            }

            if (i < height - 1) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    if (j > 1)
                        result[i + 1][j - 2] += quanterror * 3 / 48;
                    result[i + 1][j - 1] += quanterror * 5 / 48;
                }

                result[i + 1][j] += quanterror * 7 / 48;
                if (j < width - 1) {
                    result[i + 1][j + 1] += quanterror * 5 / 48;
                    if (j < width - 2)
                        result[i + 1][j + 2] += quanterror * 3 / 48;
                }
            }

            if (i < height - 2) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    if (j>1)
                        result[i + 2][j - 2] += quanterror * 1 / 48;
                    result[i + 2][j - 1] += quanterror * 3 / 48;
                }
                result[i + 2][j] += quanterror * 5 / 48;
                if (j < width - 1) {
                    result[i + 2][j + 1] += quanterror * 3 / 48;
                    if (j < width - 2)
                        result[i + 2][j + 2] += quanterror * 1 / 48;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 5) {
        cout << "usage:" << endl << "prog.exe <filename> <width> <height> <dithering>" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    stringstream w(argv[2]);
    stringstream h(argv[3]);
    stringstream d(argv[4]);
    int numcols, numrows, dithering;

    if (!(w >> numcols)) {
        cout << "width is not a number" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (numcols < 1) {
        cout << "width must be more than zero" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!(h >> numrows)) {
        cout << "height is not a number" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (numrows < 1) {
        cout << "height must be more than zero" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!(d >> dithering)) {
        cout << "dithering is not a number" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (dithering < 0 || dithering>4) {
        cout << "dithering must be [0-4]" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    srand(time(0));
    ofstream file;

    file.open(argv[1]);

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "can't open file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    file << "P5" << "\n";

    file << numrows << " " << numcols << "\n";

    file << 255 << "\n";

    vector<vector<int>> pixmap{ make_gradient(numrows, numcols) };
    switch (dithering) {
    case 1:
        pixmap = ordered_dither(numrows, numcols, pixmap);
        break;
    case 2:
        pixmap = random_dither(numrows, numcols, pixmap);
        break;
    case 3:
        pixmap = fs_dither(numrows, numcols, pixmap);
        break;
    case 4:
        pixmap = jjn_dither(numrows, numcols, pixmap);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    for_each(pixmap.begin(), pixmap.end(), [&](const auto& v) {
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<char>{file, ""});
    });

    file.close();

}
```

Comment: А что вам не нарвится в этом градиенте? Цвета переходят аккуратно, 48 -> 49 -> 50 -> … Дизеринга на этой картинке нету.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно сначала определиться, что же вы пытаетесь сделать. Ваши функции на первый взгляд берут значения в палитре 256 тонов из исходного градиента и пытаются выполнять на них какой-то дизеринг снова в ту же самую палитру 256 тонов. Это какая-то бессмыслица.

Во-первых, ваши исходные данные уже "полосаты" - вы их сами так нарисовали. Если полосы изначально есть, то устранять их дизерингом уже поздно. Дизеринг не будет устранять "полосатость" исходных данных, а наоборот, постарается изо всех сил сохранить ее. В этом и состоит основная задача дизеринга: пользуясь более скудной палитрой постараться максимально точно передать все детали исходного изображения. Полосатый градиент должен остаться полосатым.

Во-вторых, вы делаете дизеринг из палитры 256 тонов в точно такую же палитру 256 тонов. Так откуда же и зачем тут возьмется дизеринг если палитры одинаковы? Все пикселы переводятся один-в-один без ошибки - никакого дизеринга тут не нужно.

Вам, по-видимому, нужно изначально применить дизерниг, чтобы с нуля нарисовать градиент без "полосатости". Если ваш градиент имеет высоту `height`, то вам нужно мысленно предполагать, что вы рисуете этот градиент в воображаемой идеальной палитре, которая поддерживает все тона от `0` до `height - 1`. То есть если ваш градиент имеет высоту `1000`, то вы должны вообразить, что исходная идеальная палитра имеет `1000` тонов от черного до белого. Но реальная палитра не имеет `1000` тонов, она имеет только `256` тонов. И вот тут-то вы применяете дизеринг, чтобы перейти от этой воображаемой идеальной палитры к реальной палитре с тонами от `0` до `255`.

---

Ваши функции `ordered_dither` и `random_dither` не делают вообще ничего, ибо "закрыты" заведомо ложным условием

```
int requiredShade = ...;
if ((requiredShade > 0) && (requiredShade < 1))
```

Целочисленное значение не может быть одновременно `> 0` и `< 1`.

Ваша функции `fs_dither` и `jjn_dither` ничего не делают вообще, ибо в них `quanterror` всегда равно `0`.

В результате вы выводите ваш исходный градиент, никакого дизеринга к нему не применяя. А то, что он состоит из полос - там вы его сами таким и нарисовали в `make_gradient`.